# Get XML fields after SOAP call

Tags: php, asmx

My asmx WEB service return this XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <PRODUCT>
     <DESC>Vanilla ice cream</DESC>
     <CODEERR>0</CODEERR>
   </PRODUCT>
```

Calling WEB service from this PHP code

```
  $SoapCli = new SoapClient('http://www.foo.com/MyService.asmx?WSDL');
        $params = array(
          'PARAM1' => 'some_param_1',
          'PARAM2' => 'some_param_2',
        );
        $resp_WS = $SoapCli->__soapCall('MyFunction', array($params));
        var_dump($resp_WS);
```

result is

```
object(stdClass)#11946 (1) {
  ["MyFunctionResult"]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#11947 (1) {
    ["any"]=&gt;
    string(88) "<product xmlns=""><desc>Vanilla ice cream</desc><codeerr>0</codeerr></product>"
  }
}
```

but, after googling a lot, I don't find PHP code for retreive values ​​of two fields DESC and CODER

Comment: Your XML is at `$resp_WS->MyFunctionResult->any`. From there you can parse it using one of the methods in the duplicate (SimpleXML is probably the easiest). If you have problems with the code you write to parse it, please ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode`,`json_decode`,`simplexml_load_string` to parse the XML response, try the following code snippet to read the XML response

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
         <PRODUCT>
           <DESC>Vanilla ice cream</DESC>
           <CODEERR>0</CODEERR>
         </PRODUCT>';

 $res = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),true);
```

Now you can use `$res['DESC']` and `$res['CODEERR']` to retrive the values.

Comment: I can almost understand doing this for complex XML, but after something like `$data = simplexml_load_string($xml)`, you can then use `$data->desc` - not exactly complicated.